# How to speed up js loading in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I need to speed up the ui loading time, of jquery mobile. When I tried using head.js method for loading the js files parallel, it will show the jQuery mobile UI only 3-5 sec, after showing the basic html page. I've also tried CDN hosted js files and it wont make any difference from the downloaded js files.

Is there any way to cache the jquery mobile js files, so that this will speed up the ui rendering?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to speed it up?

Comment: It is taking too much for loading the UI in android webview.

Answer (score 6):

### Compress Your Javascript

When using other plugins or even your code always use compressed js files. They are smaller and will load much faster. If you take a look you will see that jQuery and jQuery Mobile are offering compressed versions.

You should also compress your js files. [**Packer**](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) tool can be found easily.

### Analyze your js files loading

Find problematic files by analyzing js file initialization. You can use addons like **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)**. It shows a breakdown of files – just go to the “Net” tab. You can also filter by file type.

[image]

### Use correct js file source

If you are creating a Phonegap application all your js files should be stored locally but if you are using it as a normal web application then use CDN source like it is mentioned in the question.

### Optimize Javascript Placement

Place your javascript at the end of your HTML file if possible. Notice how Google analytic and other stat tracking software wants to be right before the closing  tag.

This allows the majority of page content (like images, tables, text) to be loaded and rendered first. The user sees content loading, so the page looks responsive. At this point, the heavy javascripts can begin loading near the end.

Basically initialize your javascript at the HTML end, just before  tag. Sometimes this can cause problems to jQuery Mobile. In that case let jQuery and jQuery Mobile initialize in HEAD and everything else at the HTML end.

### Load Javascript On-Demand

All not necessary js files should be loaded programaticaly after the main content is loaded.

The function:

```
$import('http://example.com/myfile.js')
```

will add an element to the head of your document, just like including the file directly.

### Cache Your Files:

If you are using PHP as a server technology you can use cashing to improve loading performance. Basically you will set the browser’s cache expiration. In order to do this, you’ll need access to PHP or Apache’s .htaccess so you can send back certain cache headers (read more on caching).

### Combine Your Files

And finally when everything else brakes you should combine your js code into one single file. Your browser can only have so many connections to a website open at a time — given the overhead to set up each connection, it makes sense to combine several small scripts into a larger one.

### Gzip everything

The benefits of [**compression**](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/), often a 75% or more reduction in file size, are too good to ignore: optimize your site with HTTP compression. This method will not work on an older browser but because you are using jQuery Mobile you don't need to worry about an older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The use of CDN is encouraged is because, if the same CDN is shared on multiple sites then the files will be used from cache.

If you are using Android or iPhone WebView then it is suggested that you should not use CDNs as it disables the offline capabilities.

If your app is a web based application then consider using caching mechanisms available. This [tutorial will get you started with caching](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

Comment: I've tried HTML5 app caching and inside cache manifest I included the js files to be loaded. Evenif the js files are cached, it is taking the same time for loading from cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android WebView, you can load js from assets folder of your android app.
It's highly discouraged because you need update app every time you update js, but in some cases it's the best solution.